# Implementing a unique_ptr - PPP Stroustrup exercise

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++14, pointers

I'm doing the following exercise from PPP - Bjarne Stroustrup, Chapter 19, ex.10.

> Implement a simple `unique_ptr` supporting only a constructor, destructor,`->`, `*` and `release()`. In particular, don't try to implement an assignment or a copy constructor

Here's what I've done so far, for which I'd like to have a check. I did this without looking at available resources on this site or on the web, so I'd like to have a check and, of course, any suggestion in highly appreciated! I tried to copy the declarations from the std::unique_ptr reference on the web.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Unique_Ptr
{
private:
    T *ptr;

public:
    explicit Unique_Ptr(T *p) noexcept : ptr{p} {}

    ~Unique_Ptr() { delete ptr; };

    T *operator->() const noexcept { return ptr; }

    inline T operator*() const { return *ptr; }

    inline T *get() const noexcept { return ptr; }

    T *release() noexcept
    {
        auto tmp = ptr;
        ptr = nullptr;
        return tmp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //Constructor test
    Unique_Ptr p{new int{2}};
    std::cout << *p << "\n";

    //Test with pointer to a vector
    Unique_Ptr pp{new std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}};
    std::cout << pp->size() << "\n";

    //release() test
    auto test_release = pp.release();
    std::cout << (pp.get() == nullptr) << "\n"; //expect 1

    std::cout << test_release->size() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to deal with copy / move constructors and assignments - their implementation and declarations are missing. Also default one ought to set `ptr` to `nullptr`.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 3 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to ask a new question! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to write `inline` when a function is defined inside the class.  You might notice that you've used it in some but not all of them; it doesn't add anything to the meaning.

> In particular, don't try to implement an assignment [operator] or a copy constructor

(N.B.  did you leave out the word *operator* when you typed the quotation?)

Rather than leaving them off, which will cause an incorrect default implementation to be generated, mark them as `=delete`.  That way you'll get an error if your test code would try to make use of them, rather than just some bizarre malfunction.  Use the "rule of 5".

`T *operator->()`
That looks odd...
The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

The problem did specify *a constructor* implying the singular.  And you've given one, which prevents a default constructor from being automatically generated.  But you could add a default constructor or add a default argument to your one-argument constructor, without getting into territory that's too advanced for you.

`std::cout << test_release->size() << "\n";`
This should cause a run-time error when it dereferences the nullptr.  That's not a good way to implement a test program, especially without commenting that.

BTW, using `'\n'` instead of `"\n"` is more efficient.

### All in all, it looks good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question with the fixed code. I need, however, a check on my move semantics. I wrote in the edit what's my issue

Comment: I've posted a new question here with the improved version you suggested: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/267976/improving-my-implementation-of-a-unique-ptr-ppp-stroustrup-book

Comment: `operator->()` should also return a `T&`, not a `T*`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The default constructor is missing.
2. The move constructor and move assignment operator are missing (they are *not* copying!).

Otherwise, it looks good.

Although a matter of style, I find that it helps to indicate pointer types even when using `auto`, i.e.

```
auto* test_release = pp.release();
```

When writing "ad hoc" tests, prefer to use `assert` instead of writing to the console. You don't need human eyes to verify that the results are correct:

```
constexpr auto N = std::vector<int>::size_type(3);

auto *const vector = new std::vector<int>(N);
std::iota(vector->begin(), vector->end(), 0);
assert(vector->size() == N);

Unique_Ptr pp{vector};
assert(pp->get() == vector);
assert(pp->size() == N);

auto *test_release = pp.release();
assert(!pp->get());
assert(test_release == vector);
assert(test_release->size() == N);
```

Such tests are then very easy to convert to use an actual testing framework. E.g. for the [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/assertions.md) framework, just replace `assert` with `REQUIRE` or `CHECK` (those two are equivalent, the latter continues testing even if the statement wasn't true).

Output to console may be useful when debugging, but even then examining the state in the debugger may save time.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. I've updated my code using your suggestions about `assert`.